# Не передается фрейм данных через flask sessions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, сессия

Ошибка состоит в том, что в конечном файле CSV файл открывает только заголовки и все слитно без разделителей и данных просто нет!

У меня в 1 `@app.route` генерируются разные фреймы  данных. Мне нужно их передать в другой `@app.route` для скачивания.

```
@app.route('/dataupload_2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dataupload_2():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csv_data' in request.files:
        file = request.files['csv_data']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        #преобразования с датафрейм pandas функциями
        session["data_3"] = res_new_1.to_json()
        #передача датафрейма

@app.route('/download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getPlotCSV():
    dat = session.get('data_3')
    dat = pd.read_json(dat)
    return Response(
        dat,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=myplot.csv"})
```

Помогите сделать так, что фрейм данных открывался в CSV полностью и нормально?..

Comment: [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38635222/5741205) пробовали?

Comment: пока нет, сейчас попробую.

Comment: попробовала сейчас, но сейчас все также в самую первую ячейку только заголовки записываются :(

Comment: ну тогда надо ждать спецов по `flask` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

вы забыли преобразовать DataFrame в CSV файл при вызове `Response()`:

```
@app.route('/download', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getPlotCSV():
    dat = session.get('data_3')
    dat = pd.read_json(dat)
    return Response(
        dat.to_csv(index=False),    # <------------------- NOTE !!!
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=myplot.csv"})
```